# How Do You Create a Page that Selects and Clones part of a Document Library in Sharepoint 2007?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss, wss, sharepoint-designer

I am trying to set up a MySite allowing individuals to create and modify multiple projects, each which will contain a partial copy of a master Document Library. I have already created the Library and uploaded the documents, and I have a page on which I have been experimenting with how to do this.

I need to be able to display a list of the documents in the document library, allow the user to select which ones they want, and then when they click on a button, I need to initialize the database with some information about that prjoect, some information about each of the files, and the documents need to be copied to a new location, so that the user can pull them up and edit and save the changes that are specific to the one project.  Also we will need to be able to be able to add/remove them through a similar interface after the project has already been created, if possible.

And, unfortunately, anything at all that uses code has been restricted; so, we can't use anything that will require anything to be installed in the GAC, and I can't even use any server-side scripts within the ASPX file. It seems like almost everything I find when I search for "Sharepoint 2007 clone Master Document Library" or the like involves using code.

I have been playing around with things in SharePoint designer for creating the UI, and I figured out how to get a list of the documents to show, although I'm having a hard time duplicating it. It created a `<WebPartPages:DataFormWebPart>` with a `<SharePoint:SPDataSource>` in it. However, when I've tried to pull over things like a `Data View CheckBoxList` to the document list, either it just won't let me drop it (this includes anywhere on the form, not just in the document  list), or, as expected actually, it doesn't actually bind to each line of the list. It's not entirely clear to me what to do to create this.

I do get (more or less) that you can bind the controls via the .xslt in the form, but I'm figuring it's got to be simpler than writing them by hand since the designer looks so much like the Visual Studio designer. I am having a very hard time figuring out what exactly to do to get *any* of the controls to work, though; most of them have the same issue as the `CheckBoxList` and won't even drop on the form. I'm assuming there's a panel of some type, or some other thing, that I need to add to the form first, but this is so different from what I'm used to that I'm having a hard time even getting my bearings.

So, can someone point me in the right direction here? I'm going to need to be able to create the projects, select the documents, copy them over with some other information into a new project, including creating some items in the database. I have been developing software for a long time, on many different platforms with many different languages, although lately it's mainly been WinForms, with a fair bit of .aspx stuff (but nothing too fancy), and it's never been this hard. I figure there's just something I'm not getting about the model here; like, how do you tell the form you want to use x/y/z control connected to particular datasource? How do you tell sharepoint to create a new location for the files? How can you submit the selected files once you have them to Sharepoint and tell them where to copy to?

Any help would be so appreciated I have been tearing my hair out for days. :)

Answer (score 1):

You might have had a change with SharePoint 2010, as there is a javascript/jQuery programming model, but without that you don't have a realistic of coding what you will need. You may get lucky and be able to [call the SharePoint web services using jQuery](http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2009/04/09/calling-the-sharepoint-web-services-with-jquery.aspx), but it is going to be a lot of work to get around a "no code" requirement.

Comment: +1 and thanks for your response. :) I have looked into the JQuery model a bit; I am serving up the latest version on my site, and have been able to insert it into a Content Editor Web Part. of course, it figures that tonight my site somehow got screwed up and stopped letting the Designer access the Web Part gallery on the server so I'm uninstalling and getting ready to reinstall now... If it takes JQuery that's fine, but I was hoping *some* of this first part was going to be doable without having to go that route. Am I just whistling in the dark on that?

Comment: Also, do you know whether it is possible to set up the JQuery stuff in such a way as to allow the UI setup to also work with server-side scripting w/ C#? It's very *slightly* possible that they will let us do that, although I've been waiting a week for an answer now and so far the answer has been "no" to absolutely everything else that we couldn't enable via our site admin. (e.g. I have a hunch that modifying the web.config is going to be completely out of the question despite the fact that it's only our site's that needs modification.)

Comment: So far the JQuery stuff I have found seems completely differently designed from the way C# stuff I found was done, but I am not sure whether that's due to any inherent differences between the way they operate.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, well, I was finally able to get this mostly working, although there are still some issues with displaying the data once I get it back; I will try to update this question once I have a better answer for that.

There's a cool library called [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) which combines with JQuery to give an interface to the web services for SharePoint 2007.  It seems to more or less provide an interface to anything that you need to do to use the web services without a lot of extra work on your part.

For example, to query a document library, I set up a function something like this in a helper class (based upon [the examples from the SPServices documentation](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=GetListItems&referringTitle=Lists)).

```
ServiceClass.prototype.getSpecialDocLib = function (onComplete) {
    var sc = this;

    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        async: false,
        listName: "Special Document Library",
        CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields>",

        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
            var outTable = new DocTable();

            $(xData.responseXML).find("[nodeName='z:row']").each(function () {
                var i;
                var outRow = new DocTableRow();

                for (i = 0; i < this.attributes.length; ++i) {
                    outRow.addField(this.attributes[i].localName, this.attributes[i].value);
                };

                outTable.addRow(outRow);
            });

            sc.onDocumentListComplete(xData, Status);

            if (onComplete != null)
                onComplete(resultTable);
        }
    });
};
```

For copying a document library from one place to another, I believe you can use [Lists](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Lists&referringTitle=%24%28%29.SPServices).AddList to create it, (not specifically documented in SPServices but is based upon [this Web Service call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.addlist.aspx)) either from scratch or a template, and I believe you can use the SPServices [Copy.CopyIntoItemsLocal](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CopyIntoItemsLocal&referringTitle=Copy) method.

Anyway, I seem to be making progress with this so far; I will update and accept this answer once I have a little more experience and time to make sure everything works, but so far I seem to be making progress toward the "no code" goal.